# Why does it give me error with line 26 / wall.body.appendChild(wall); /?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Whenever I try to run this code, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined". Can anyone explain why and how to fix this? I want to make a maze, and be able to change the size by editing the block. I am attempting to create a sprite that will repeat were there is a 1 but it won't create multiple sprite at once because of line 26 / wall.body.appendChild(wall); /

```
// Create a 2D array to represent the maze
// 1 represents a wall and 0 represents a path
var maze = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
];

// Create a function to generate the maze
function draw() {
  // Loop through the maze array to create the walls and paths
  for (var i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
      if (maze[i][j] == 1) {
        // Create a wall
        var wall = createSprite("div");
        wall.className = "wall";
        wall.setAnimation("wall");
        wall.body.appendChild(wall);
      } else {
        // Create a path
        var path = document.createElement("div");
        path.className = "path";
        path.style.backgroundImage = "url('path.png')";
        document.body.appendChild(path);
      }
    }
  }

  // Create a player sprite
  var player = document.createElement("div");
  player.className = "player";
  player.style.backgroundImage = "url('player.png')";
  document.body.appendChild(player);
}
```

Comment: The error basically says that `wall` doesn't have a `body` property.  Did you mean `document.body.appendChild(wall)`?

Comment: @James I don't entirely understand how this code works, I have just found this in one of my junk folders unfinished and I wanted to finish it. How would I implement this into my code?

Comment: By replacing the line that causes the error with what I suggested, and then testing it.

Comment: @James It's now saying 'Oops, we can't figure out what document is - perhaps you meant the string "document" with quotes? If this is meant to be a variable, make sure you declared a variable'

Comment: `It's now saying ...` - what environment is this code being run in?

Comment: @James I am running it on code.org since I don't know how to do html and CSS reliably yet, and now that I think about it, it is possible that it doesn't have that programed into it.